# What does "<" mean in iptables-restore < [file]?

Tags: command-line

What does "<" do in `iptables-restore < [file]?`

Additionally, what does this command do? Does it change the file?

Are there other commands or ways to use "<"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` tells the shell to *redirect* the contents of the file to the `iptables-restore` command's *standard input*. The file itself is not modified.

For a more complete discussion see, for example

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)